# vagrant with salt provisioning - running a particular state

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, salt-stack, vagrant-plugin

Is there a way I can use the salt provisioner to run only a handful of states rather than doing a full highstate?

Our full highstate does a bunch of stuff that doesn't make sense for an ephemperal development VM, and in fact, a lot of which just won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin itself only currently supports running a full highstate.

As a workaround, you could first tell vagrant not to run highstate:

```
config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
     salt.run_highstate = false
end
```

Then you could use a shell provisioner to run the chosen states:

```
config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "salt-call --local state.sls foo,bar"
end
```